# MooTools - delay between "each" iterations

Tags: javascript, mootools, delay

I need to set delays between "each" iteration

```js
if (index == 3) {
    $$('.check').each(function (el, ind) {
        if (ind > 0) {
            $$('.check')[ind - 1].addClass('hide');
        };
        $$('.check')[ind].removeClass('hide'); /*here should come delay*/
    });
}
```

Please advice ;)

Comment: Why? Take a look at the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-do-i-do-if-i-want-a-javascript-version-of-sleep

Answer (score 2):

As Sergio said, you can use the index in the iteration for a cascading effect.

```
(function(){
    // don't always lookup through DOM, cache el references if they are 
    // not changing dynamically
    var checks = $$('.check'),
        index = 3;

    // ...

    if (index === 3){
        checks.each(function(el, i){
            // i truthy is enough.
            i && checks[i-1].addClass('hide');
            // use a 100ms incremental delay for each next el
            this.delay(i*100, el, 'hide');
        }, Element.prototype.removeClass);
    }
}());
```

the `Function.prototype.delay` can be applied on `Element.prototype.removeClass` (used as context for fun).

keep in mind that the above is broken - we can't see all your code or the intent behind it. delaying the applied `removeClass` will work but it will undo the `addClass('hide')` later so you'd end up with all elements visible.

Comment: Smart `this.delay(i*100, el, 'hide')` :) `+1`

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to do [a kind of *highlight*](http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.5.1/Fx/Fx.Tween#Element:highlight). You can use a native `setTimeout` for that. You have 2 options:

- #1 animate all looped elements at the same time
- #2 animate looped elements one at a time

#### option #1

```
if (index == 3) {
    var check = $$('.check'); // cache this, once.
    var delay = 1000; // 1 second
    check.each(function (el, ind) {
        if (ind > 0) {
            check[ind - 1].addClass('hide');
        };
        (function () {  // to lock the value of ind
            var i = ind;
            setTimeout(function () {
                check[i].removeClass('hide'); /*here should come delay*/
            }, delay);
        })();
    });
}
```

#### option #2

This case is very similar but multiplies the delay time by the index of the iteration and making animation delay/timeout bigger for each loop iteration

```
if (index == 3) {
    var check = $$('.check'); // cache this, once.
    var delay = 1000; // 1 second
    check.each(function (el, ind) {
        if (ind > 0) {
            check[ind - 1].addClass('hide');
        };
        (function () {  // to lock the value of ind
            var i = ind;
            setTimeout(function () {
                check[i].removeClass('hide'); /*here should come delay*/
            }, delay * i);
        })();
    });
}
```